# What's the difference between a column with a default and a column with a default constraint?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

A default value of a column can be added like this

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MyColumn]
```

or like this

```
ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_MyTable_MyColumn]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [MyColumn]
```

What is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The constraint in the first example will be assigned a name by SQL Server.

Comment: It also allows you to easily drop the constraint (since it has a name!)

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server peculiarly classifies defaults as "constraints". The syntax using the CONSTRAINT keyword allows you to specify a name for the default, which is good practice.